# Unable to get data from dataimport.properties to config solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, dataimporthandler

I am using dataimporthandler for solr.
I am trying to put some data in the dataimport.properties file for my db-data-config.xml

Here is my config file :

```
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource batchSize="-1" driver="${dataimporter.driverName}"
.....
```

here is my dataimport.properties file:

```
#Thu May 04 06:49:58 UTC 2017
driverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
last_index_time=2017-05-04 06\:49\:51
IndData.last_index_time=2017-05-04 06\:49\:51
```

if i put the exact driver name in my config file it works.
But i want that data from my properties file.

Can someone please help me regarding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think dataimport.properties file allows you to put any arbitrary piece of data there and use it later in the DIH.

What you can do on the other hand is:

1. keep your driverName value in your own .properties file
2. upon callilng DIH, add this to the request url

   ```
    /dataimport&command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true&driverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   ```
3. and it should be picked up in your current db-data-config.xml